# list of tuples to list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

This must me very easy, but I can't seem to find a one-line/efficiënt solution :

I want to convert `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]` in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: related: [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279)

Comment: If only I used the word flattening in my endless search. (I know the word, it just didn't pop in my mind.)